# How is input data distributed across nodes for EMR [using MRJob]?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, partitioning, elastic-map-reduce, mrjob

I'm looking into using Yelp's MRJob to compute using Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce.  I will need to read and write a large amount of data during the computationally intensive job.  Each node should only get a part of the data, and I'm confused about how this is done. Currently, my data is in a MongoDB and is stored on a persistent EBS drive.

When using EMR, how is the data factored over the nodes?  How should one tell MRJob which key to partition the data over?  The [MRJob EMR documentation](http://packages.python.org/mrjob/runners-emr.html) leaves the factoring step implicit: if you open a file or connection to a S3 key-value store, how does it divide the keys?  Does it assume that the input is a sequence and partition it automatically on that basis?

Perhaps someone can explain how input data is propagated to nodes using the [MRJob wordcount example](http://packages.python.org/mrjob/writing-and-running.html).  In that example, the input is a text file -- is it copied to all nodes, or read serially by one node and distributed in pieces?

Answer (score 1):

That example assumes you are working with text files.  I'm not sure you can pass in a parameter to use the MongoDB hadoop driver.

What are you trying to do here?  I'm working on the MongoDB hadoop driver and I'm looking for examples and test cases.

Comment: What an opportunity! :-)  So, MongoDB does MapReduce, but it only parallelizes if you use shards and requires programming in JavaScript (ugh).  I'm looking to take millions of records of English text, parse them (2sec/record) using Python libraries, and save them back. I'd be happy to work with you and supply test examples/code.

Comment: My email address is in my profile.

I'm still new to hadoop.  I'm not sure how the python api works.  You'll have to help me out there.